# Python Neural Networking: Connecting Nodes together

Tags: python, connection, neural-network, nodes

I am new to coding and I am having a lot of trouble with this "simple" program.

So I am trying to connect the 3 Nodes in the "nodes" list that I have created together. In the Node class I have defined an add connection and made a Connection class to bind these all together.

But when I try to "Node.addconnection" it gives me "unbound method". And if I tried to "Node.addconnection(Node(), Node())" I thought this would connect 2 nodes together. But it gives me an infinite loop of errors.

```
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 

nodes=[] 
NUMNODES=3

# 
#                                   Node Class
# 

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name=name 
        self.activation_threshold=0.0
        self.net_input=0.0
        self.outgoing_connections=[] 
        self.incoming_connections=[] 
        self.activation=None

    def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0): 
        self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 
        for i in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them i 
            for j in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them j 
                if i!=j:#as long as i and j are not the same 
                    nodes[i].AddConnection(nodes[j])#connects the nodes together 

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.connections: 
            self.net_input += conn.wt * conn.sender.activation 
        print 'Updated Input is', self.net_input 

    def update_activation(self): 
        self.activation = self.net_input - 0.5
        print 'Updated Activation is', self.activation 

# 
#                                   Connection Class
# 

class Connection(object): 

    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight=1.0): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever 
        sender.outgoing_connections.append(self) 
        reciever.incoming_connections.append(self) 
# 
#                                 Other Programs 
# 

def set_activations(act_vector): 
    """Activation vector must be same length as nodes list"""
    for i in xrange(len(act_vector)): 
        nodes[i].activation = act_vector[i] 

for i in xrange(NUMNODES): 
    nodes.append(Node()) 

for i in xrange(10): 
    for thing in nodes: 
        thing.update_activation 
        thing.update_input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to connect all the nodes together when calling "addconnection", by calling… addconnection. Hence, the recursion.

If you try to connect all your nodes in your "other programs" part, it will be better :

```
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 

nodes=[] 
NUMNODES=3

# 
#                                   Node Class
# 

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name=name 
        self.activation_threshold=0.0
        self.net_input=0.0
        self.outgoing_connections=[] 
        self.incoming_connections=[] 
        self.connections=[] 
        self.activation=None

    def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0): 
        #just add the connection
        self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.connections: 
            self.net_input += conn.weight * conn.sender.activation 
        print 'Updated Input is', self.net_input 

    def update_activation(self): 
        self.activation = self.net_input - 0.5
        print 'Updated Activation is', self.activation 

# 
#                                   Connection Class
# 

class Connection(object): 
    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight=1.0): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever 
        sender.outgoing_connections.append(self) 
        reciever.incoming_connections.append(self) 
# 
#                                 Other Programs 
# 


def set_activations(act_vector): 
    """Activation vector must be same length as nodes list"""
    for i in xrange(len(act_vector)): 
        nodes[i].activation = act_vector[i] 


for i in xrange(NUMNODES): 
    nodes.append(Node()) 

#do the connections here
from random import random
for i in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them i 
    for j in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them j 
        if i!=j:#as long as i and j are not the same 
            nodes[i].addconnection(nodes[j],random())#connects the nodes together 

for i in xrange(10): 
    for thing in nodes: 
        thing.update_activation() 
        thing.update_input()


...
Updated Activation is -0.5
Updated Input is -0.452698580538
Updated Activation is -0.5
Updated Input is -0.336733968936
Updated Activation is -0.5
Updated Input is -0.204908511332
Updated Activation is -0.952698580538
Updated Input is -0.862570590181
Updated Activation is -0.836733968936
Updated Input is -0.563513500607
Updated Activation is -0.704908511332
Updated Input is -0.288883507365
Updated Activation is -1.36257059018
...
```

Comment: Oh, because I was connecting the nodes to itself, it just kept looping around. Thanks!